# How to remove my username from my question?

Tags: discussion

I've asked and gotten a satisfactory answer to my question, but now I want to disown the question. I don't want to delete it, but just make it that my username doesn't appear. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think there's a feature built-in, and I honestly don't see a need for it. You could try flagging for moderator attention (via the "Other") option and explain why you need that. By the way: why?

Comment: @JoachimSauer My username here (on stack sites) differ from my public name, and before sharing my awesome findings, I was thinking whether it would be possible to not inadvertently link the two identities.. /tinfoilhat

Comment: @laggingreflex You can change your display name by editing your profile!

Comment: @hjpotter92 Change to what? (they're already different BTW) I think I didn't make it clear.. I didn't want to link the two identities (were it possible) for even other humans to figure out. All my account's history is still linked to the question (indirectly).